# GPU disabled when including tensorflow into packages while training on Google Cloud

Tags: tensorflow, gcloud

I'm training a `tensorflow` `python` model on Google Cloud.

When I include my personal package using `--packages utils-0.0.1.tar.gz`, which is generated by `python setup.py sdist` from some `setup.py` file with `tensorflow` package in it, this leads to that GPU is not found on the Cloud and training goes fully on CPU (no error shown), even if `config.yaml` has GPU `standard_p100` specified directly.

As soon as I remove `tensorflow` from the `setup.py` and recreate the package `utils-0.0.1.tar.gz`, the GPU is shown available and is used for training.

To mention, the training `setup.py` file doesn't have any packages to be additionally installed.

Train:

```py
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
    --staging-bucket $PACKAGE_STAGING_PATH \
    --job-dir $OUTPUT_PATH \
    --runtime-version 1.10 \
    --module-name model.train \
    --packages utils-0.0.1.tar.gz \
    --package-path model/ \
    --region $REGION \
    --config config.yaml \
    --python-version 2.7 \
    -- \
    --param_file params.yaml
```

I think, that `tensorflow` in the package `utils-0.0.1.tar.gz` overwrites some GPU settings.

I expect that GPU is used no matter if `tensorflow` is specified in the additional packages.

Comment: Could you try replacing `tensorflow` with `tensorflow-gpu` and check if it works for you?

Comment: Yes, when replacing `tensorflow` with `tensorflow-gpu` everything is fine (cloud GPU is available). In fact, I don't really need to specify any of these two packages, but this is just strange why specifying `tensorflow` in setup file disables cloud GPU